# Imagemagick: compose 2 images where 1 wraps the other

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I want to make a wrapping image or gif that when composed with a different image will wrap it like the wrapping image.

For example combining these two images:

[image]

[image]

Would yield this image

[image]

I don't want an imagemagick command that does this specific movement of pixels because then it wouldn't be modular.

Comment: I do not understand your comment "I don't want an imagemagick command that does this specific movement of pixels because then it wouldn't be modular." How do you want to control the amount of overlap and how many overlaps there are?

Comment: The second image i posted of the gradient would be controlling the overlap but I'm starting to realise this is basically impossible (unless i want to play around with neural networks or something crazy). Your answer is still very useful so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way in Imagemagick using the -roll function. But unfortunately it does not use percent. So I have to do a separate computation in IM 6 to convert percent to pixels. In IM 7 it could be done in one command apart from setting the pct overlap and split.

Here I cut the image into 3 sections (33% each, though different amounts could be used). And then roll the middle sections by 33% to the right with wrap around.

IM 6

```
pct=33
rollx=`convert palmtree.png -format "%[fx:round($pct*w/100)]" info:`
convert palmtree.png \( -clone 0 -gravity north -crop 100%x$pct%+0+0 +repage \) \( -clone 0 -gravity center -crop 100%x$pct%+0+0 +repage -roll +${rollx}+0 \) \( -clone 0 -gravity south -crop 100%x$pct%+0+0 +repage \) -delete 0 -append result.png
```

IM 7

```
pct=33
magick palmtree.png -set option:rollx "%[fx:round($pct*w/100)]" \( -clone 0 -gravity north -crop 100%x$pct%+0+0 +repage \) \( -clone 0 -gravity center -crop 100%x$pct%+0+0 +repage -roll +[rollx]+0 \) \( -clone 0 -gravity south -crop 100%x$pct%+0+0 +repage \) -delete 0 -append result.png
```

[image]

If you do not want 33% for all, then change the pct to whatever percent you want for each part and for the roll as desired. If you want to use multiple images, then replace each -clone with the actual image you want.